# I can't run my python codes in Windows Power Shell despite my text editor can run

Tags: python, powershell

It's my first post on this web site. I'm having a problem with running my python codes on Windows Power Shell although my Atom text editor can run. Because I've alread installed the latest python version. When I try to run codes with PowerShell it says me basicly that Python can not be found.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the exact command you're running, along with the (exact) error message :)

Answer (score 1):

Find python (`where /R \ python.exe`) and add it to your path (win+r `systempropertiesadvanced`, go to environment variables, find `PATH` under the top box, start editing it, then add the `python.exe` directory to path.) Then restart powershell.

Comment: Either that or call python using its full path and handing in your script.